# Copy cells with format from an excel worksheet to another workbook worksheet in Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, copy, range, cells

> In a worksheet there is:

[image: This is a header]

I want unmerge the B2:C2 cell and copy with its format to the other sheet (in another workbook) at A1, then the value (in C3) to the B1 cell of the other sheet, D2 to A2, E2 to B2 and so...
How can I do?

[image: This is a detail]

```
procedure Something;
const root = 'C:\vial\$$652791.xls';
     filename = 'C:\vial\abarajame.xls';
var xlsH, xlsD: TExcelApplication;
    sheetH,sheetD: _Worksheet;
    DestRange: OleVariant;
    format: string;
begin
    xlsH := TExcelApplication.Create(Self);
    xlsD := TExcelApplication.Create(Self);
    xlsH.Workbooks.Open(root, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, 0 );
    xlsD.Workbooks.Open(filename, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
    EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, 0 );
    sheetH := xlsH.Worksheets[1] as _Worksheet;
    sheetD := xlsD.Worksheets[1] as _Worksheet;
    //Insert 5 empty rows
    sheetD.Rows.Range['A1','A5'].EntireRow.Insert(xlShiftDown, Null);
    //1st. col.
    sheetH.Cells.Range['B2','I2'].MergeCells := False;
    DestRange := sheetH.Cells.Range['B2','I2'];
    format    := sheetH.Cells.Range['B2','I2'].NumberFormat;
    sheetD.Cells.Range['A1','A1'].Copy(DestRange);
    sheetD.Cells.Range['A1','A1'].NumberFormat := format;
    DestRange := sheetH.Range['C3','C3'];
    format    := sheetH.Range['C3','C3'].NumberFormat;
    sheetD.Range['A2','A2'].Copy(DestRange);
    sheetD.Range['A2','A2'].NumberFormat := format;
    //2nd. col.
    DestRange := xlsH.Range['D2','D2'];
    xlsD.Range['B1','B1'].Copy(DestRange);
    DestRange := xlsH.Range['C4','C4'];
    hojaD.Range['B2','B2'].Copy(DestRange);
    xlsd.SaveWorkspace;
    xlsH.Workbooks.Close(0);
    xlsD.Workbooks.Close(0);
    FreeAndNil(xlsH);
    FreeAndNil(xlsD);
end;
```

I've tested with differents ways, Cells.Range, Range from Sheet,from Cells from ExcelApplication, but nothing does!!

Result must be:

[image: That I want to do]

Comment: Solved.
I don´t need create 2 TExcelApplication instancies. Only must open each workbook and copy from source range to destination range

Answer (score 0):

this is the mode:

```
 sheetD.Rows.Range['A1','A5'].EntireRow.Insert(xlShiftDown, Null);
  //1st. col.
  sheetH.Range['B2','B2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['A1','A1']);
  sheetH.Range['C3','C3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['B1','B1']);
  //2nd. col.
  sheetH.Range['D2','D2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['A2','A2']);
  sheetH.Range['D3','D3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['B2','B2']);
  //3rd. col.
  sheetH.Range['E2','E2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['A3','A3']);
  sheetH.Range['E3','E3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['B3','B3']);
  //4th.col
  sheetH.Range['F2','F2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['A4','A4']);
  sheetH.Range['F3','F3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['B4','B4']);
  // col.1
  sheetH.Range['G2','G2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['C1','C1']);
  sheetH.Range['G3','G3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['D1','D1']);
  // col.2
  sheetH.Range['H2','H2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['C2','C2']);
  sheetH.Range['H3','H3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['D2','D2']);
  // col.3
  sheetH.Range['I2','I2'].Copy(sheetD.Range['C3','C3']);
  sheetH.Range['I3','I3'].Copy(sheetD.Range['D3','D3']);
```